# Out of memory using BinaryWriter in C# on adding files to a zip file

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, binarywriter

I am trying to add files to a Zip file, preserving the directory. The code below is basically working as long as I do not have files of a few 100 Mb to zip. If I just zip a directory with 1 file of about 250 Mb (on a system with plenty of memory BTW) I get an OutOfMemory exception on the `write.Write()` line.

I already modified the code to read in chunks as it first failed when I read/wrote the whole file. I don't know why it still fails?

```
    using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(cZipName, eFileMode)) 
        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(cFileToBackup

);

    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
    {
        FileStream fsData = null;                                                                // Load file into FileStream
        fsData = new FileStream(cFileFull, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fsData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                 writer.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead); // here it fails
                 fsData.Flush(); // ->CHANGED  THIS TO writer.Flush() SOLVED IT - nearly..
            }
        }
        fsData.Close();
    }
```

**EDIT**: Arkadiusz K was right that I used the flush on the reader, not the writer. After changing that, the program zips files of 1 Gb or more where it stopped at 100 Mb first. However, I get another exception when I try to zip e.g. a 6 Gb file - it stops with: System.IO.IOException was unhandled **Stream was too long** Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)  (etc)

Does anybody have an idea why it still fails? I'd say th code should now properly read and write 1 Kb at a time?

Comment: Can you please put the copy-pasted error message too?

Comment: What is the platform target for your application? If it is `x86` you must remember about memory address space that  `32-bit` application can use in adress space (it's about 2GB but as far as I know it can be extended by some options)

Comment: The error is:
   {"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."}
  (-2147024882    mscorlib)
    at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
      at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   
   It's targeted at Any CPU. Interesting things is when I change that to X64, the error changes to 
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - Additional information: Stream was too long.
   In both cases it should work by adding 1 Kb at a time?

Comment: Hmm, you should rather do `writer.Flush()` instead of `fsData.Flush()`. You are only reading from `FileStream` not writing to it.

Comment: YES, this is it. I was so concentrated on assuming there was still something wrong with the concept that I totally overlooked the incorrect flush. Thank you very much for your reply! Although writing works fine, larger files which failed now work, reading is the next problem. If the files to read are too large, I now get an exception Stream was too long. Seems that this needs to get attention too.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I'd really like to format your code and make it as succinct as it should be:

```
var readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(cFileToBackup);
using (var fsData = new FileStream(cFileFull, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fsData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
         writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); // here it fails
         writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Now, to explain why it fails:

BinaryWriter is a stream writer. When it has to write the data to the stream, it usually writes it *Length-prefixed* and:

> Length-prefixed means that this method first writes the length of the
>   string, in bytes, when encoded with the BinaryWriter instance's
>   current encoding to the stream. This value is written as an unsigned
>   integer. This method then writes that many bytes to the stream.

In order to write to the file, in your case, the data is written to MemoryStream first. Here, MemoryStream is the backing store stream. Refer to the diagram below:

[image: Streams in .NET]

<sup>(Image taken from: http://kcshadow.net/wpdeveloper/sites/default/files/streamd3.png)</sup>

Because, either your system's memory is about 6-8GB or because your application has been allocated that much memory only, the backing store stream is expanded to the max possible when you attempt to zip a 6GB file, and throws the exception then onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation. That leaves the question: how can I solve this? It must be possible to read files much larger than memory and add them to a binary stream I'd say.

Comment: @Dick: I'm not confident as I haven't tried myself, but you can try with changing the backing store to File instead of Memory.

Comment: @Dick: I would like to see how you have defined `archive`.

Comment: @  displayName I'd say that the only thing happening in memory is buffering that 1 Kb?  I use a filestream to read and a Ziparchive to write to. I've added 1 line of code above; "archive" is defined in the code as archive = new ZipArchive

Comment: @Dick: It's not 1KB in memory buffering. Your code is trying to accumulate the result in memory and then finally write it back when done.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your EDIT: ran into the same issue. After some digging, I discovered that `zipFileEntry.Open()` returns a `WrappedStream`, which is the underlying stream (the one that cannot be flushed until finished writing to it).

This `WrappedStream` is the problem: its max length is of ~2GB. I couldn't find a way to get around this, so I ended up using a different compression library altogether.

Comment: Mind sharing which compression library you ended up using?